# How do I log the "id" of an object in a json file using a keyword of the "name" also located in the object?

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, keyword

I start my program by typing “node app.js” in the terminal. My overall goal is to type a specific word again into the terminal for example “pinball”. Then the program will continue to run and search the json url for the word “pinball”. Inside one of the objects of the json url is the name: “Supreme®/Stern® Pinball Machine”. It will locate that object which includes that name using the word “pinball” and console log just the id that is also inside that object. Here is a part of the json I am talking about:

```
{
    "unique_image_url_prefixes": [],
    "products_and_categories": {
        "Accessories": [{
            "name": "Supreme®/Stern® Pinball Machine",
            "id": 171495

        }]
    }
}
```

The full url of the json can be found at: http://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json
Any help is great and I am able to clarify anything that doesn't make sense. I plan on doing this for all ids in the json file, but an example on how to do one will work great to code the others. Here is the part my code that I have been working on:

```
const request = require('request')
request('http://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json', function(error, response, body) {
    const ids = Object.values(JSON.parse(body).products_and_categories).reduce((o, items) => o.concat(items.map(({
         Id
    }) => id)), [])
    console.log(ids)
})
```

In short I want to run my program, type the word "pinball" into the terminal, and it will then console log "171495"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have seen in the data, that the object contains keys and within the keys you have an array with all products of a certain categorie. This might work:

```
const request = require('request');

request('http://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json', function(error, response, body) {

    const searchword = "Pinball";

    const data = JSON.parse(body).products_and_categories;

    const ids = [];

    for (var key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            data[key].map(item => {
                if (item.name.indexOf(searchword) >= 0) {
                    ids.push(item.id);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    console.log(ids);
})
```